# Reporting statistical significance for voluntary sample

Tags: statistical-significance, sampling

I’m working with a dataset (n=300) that is based on a voluntary sample, the respondents invited their self’s in (applied on a job and completed a survey). I want to analyze my data with a logistic regression.

Does it makes sense to report the ‘significance’ alongside the coefficients?

Is there any peer reviewed work (book, paper) available that handles this kind of question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly speaking, no, it doesn't. P values are for inference and, since you don't have a random sample, strictly speaking, you shouldn't do inference (to what population would you infer?)

However, on a practical basis, people report p-values for this sort of study all the time, they just assume that their self-selected sample is representative of some population.

As to getting such research published - since you haven't told us anything about what you are studying, it's impossible to answer with any specifics, but, yes, studies based on self-selected samples do get published quite often.

Comment: at Peter Flom, first thank you. I’m studying an applicant selection process, in particular applicants who apply for a managerial job. Now, I don’t assume that the self-selected sample is representative of some population. I consider the data as case study, which it is. The thing I want to ‘show’, amongst other things, is that the decision of the employer is not merely based on educational indicators (field, level GPA etc) and that the decision is not consistent/ not that ‘rational’.

Comment: I imagine you could get such research published in a journal related to human resources or something similar. And I would be very surprised if such a field had a lot of experiments or random samples from well-defined populations.

Answer (score 0):

I would have to disagree. The issue of inference to a larger population is one related to external validity instead of internal validity. When testing coefficients, you are testing the possible effect of these coefficients on the outcome measure in 'this' sample. It says nothing about the bias that these coefficients will have on the 'general' population regardless of whether or not your sample represents the population on which you intend to project your results upon.

For example, a sample of all Caucasian males aged from 20 - 30 may not be the best sample to use to test the relationship between a drug and cognitive response in the elderly (external validity) but you can still see the relationship between the drug and brain chemistry in this population.

As for peer-reviewed publications, if you look hard enough, there is always a place for publishing your work. It may differ by impact factor, reader audience and prestige, but as long as your work is ethical and not fraudulent then there will be a place for it in the literature.

Hope this helps.

AMAS